# After customer create account & submit the form he get ERROR 500 Prestashop 1.6.1.11

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

After customer fill the the account-creation and submit the form he gets 500 ERROR (and the url we see is www.ourstoredomain.com/login) ,I know he should redirect  to my-account page . 
after refresh the page he get the login page and if he want to register again we see massage that the this mail already 
in the system , and he can login to the system , how we can fix this issue ? 
we use 1.6.1.11

Comment: Have you activated the debug mode?

Comment: Look to server error log